# How do I get the upper or lower value of a time/date range, using Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

If I have a query, that returns a date or time range, how do get the upper or lower bound?

For example, [Ramadan 1436](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ramadan+1436) returns: `Thursday, June 18, 2015  to  Friday, July 17, 2015` 
Another example is [fajr time in New York City](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=time+of+Fajr+today+in+new+york+city), which returns a range.

How do I pull out the start or end of any range, to chain it up with other queries?

I'm only interested in a generic solution,  not a specific one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think W|A will meet your needs. It is not apparently designed to support complex chaining of datetime calculations. As proof, observe the following ...

> [first day of (ramadan 1436) in Gregorian calendar](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=first%20day%20of%20%28ramadan%201436%29%20in%20Gregorian%20calendar) = Thursday, June 18, 2015

correct

> [hours from ( 12:01 am UTC, Thursday, June 18, 2015) to (23:59 pm UTC, Friday, July 17, 2015)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20hours%20from%20%28%2012%3A01%20am%20UTC%2C%20Thursday%2C%20June%2018%2C%202015%29%20to%20%2823%3A59%20pm%20UTC%2C%20Friday%2C%20July%2017%2C%202015%29) = 720 hours aka 30 days

correct

but a simple substitution in brackets gives ...

> [hours from ( 12:01 am UTC, (first day of (ramadan 1436) in Gregorian calendar)) to (23:59 pm UTC, Friday, July 17, 2015)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hours%20from%20%28%2012%3A01%20am%20UTC%2C%20%28first%20day%20of%20%28ramadan%201436%29%20in%20Gregorian%20calendar%29%29%20to%20%2823%3A59%20pm%20UTC%2C%20Friday%2C%20July%2017%2C%202015%29)

... a senseless answer by adding in extra assumed terms.

as regard finding fractions of datetime ranges only basic queries seem to work. For example

> [0.75 * (hours from ( 12:01 am UTC, Thursday, June 18, 2015) to (23:59 pm UTC, Friday, July 17, 2015))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.75%20*%20%28hours%20from%20%28%2012%3A01%20am%20UTC%2C%20Thursday%2C%20June%2018%2C%202015%29%20to%20%2823%3A59%20pm%20UTC%2C%20Friday%2C%20July%2017%2C%202015%29%29) = 540 hours

works

but W|A cannot understand adding a start date to that as follows ...

> [( 12:01 am UTC, Thursday, June 18, 2015) + (0.75 * (hours from ( 12:01 am UTC, Thursday, June 18, 2015) to (23:59 pm UTC, Friday, July 17, 2015)))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%2012%3A01%20am%20UTC%2C%20Thursday%2C%20June%2018%2C%202015%29%20%2B%20%280.75%20*%20%28hours%20from%20%28%2012%3A01%20am%20UTC%2C%20Thursday%2C%20June%2018%2C%202015%29%20to%20%2823%3A59%20pm%20UTC%2C%20Friday%2C%20July%2017%2C%202015%29%29%29)

**answer to earlier version of question**

this works for the first day

[first day of (ramadan 1436) in Gregorian calendar](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=first%20day%20of%20%28ramadan%201436%29%20in%20Gregorian%20calendar) = Thursday, June 18, 2015

and this works for the final day

[(first day of (ramadan 1436) in Gregorian calendar) + (number of days in ramadan 1436) - (1 day)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28first%20day%20of%20%28ramadan%201436%29%20in%20Gregorian%20calendar%29%20%2B%20%28number%20of%20days%20in%20ramadan%201436%29%20-%20%281%20day%29)  = Friday, July 17, 2015

Comment: How would you do it for time ranges?

Comment: not sure I understand clearly. "Thursday, June 18, 2015  to  Friday, July 17, 2015" is a "time range". can you give an exact example of a "time range" and exactly the answer you expect ? please. You might want to consider asking this as a separate question.

Comment: Initially I was going to add one, as searching on W|A for prayer times would give a start and end range as a time (rather than a date). But that feature doen't seem to be working at the moment...

Comment: would something like "time of Fajr today in new york city" help you ?

Comment: [time of Fajr today in new york city](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=time+of+Fajr+today+in+new+york+city) give me: 3:30 am EDT  to  5:30 am EDT which again a range. Is there a generic way to get that?

Comment: do you wish to get just "3:30 am EDT" as an answer ? BTW, I'm no expert but I understand the Salat prayers times are supposed to be ranges ?

Comment: they are,  but I still want to know when they start. For instance if I want to calculate 3/4 of the way through the asr prayer,  or half way between the end of Maghrib and Fajr I will need to be able to isolate the start and end times.

Comment: ok, so for say "half between 3:30 am EDT to 5:30 am EDT" the answer you want is "04:30 am EDT" ? . this would be assuming an accuracy of 1 minute is required (as opposed to day a second or a half-hour or whatever). If you ask this as a new question I will attempt to answer it. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit...teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24262/discussion-between-john-mcnamara-and-pureferret).

Comment: updated ... I think you're gonna need a bigger boat :-]